# Invalid or unsupported currency code paypal error when using multiple currency

Tags: paypal

I am using payflow pro. When I use currency code 'USD' all payment flow's works fine. But when I change currency code to 'CAD' it will return error with result code 06 which means Invalid or unsupported currency code. How to solve this problem?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: // The currency code'CURRENCY' => 'USD'

Comment: add [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your code by [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33300953/edit).

Answer (score 1):

This is not problem with your code.
Following  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/

```
Payment Receiving Preferences
If you have a PayPal Premier or Business account, configure your Payment 
Receiving Preferences to handle payments automatically. You can convert 
any payment into your primary currency or block certain types of payments.

You can set the following:

Block or unblock payments from U.S. customers who don’t have a confirmed address.
Block or unblock payments sent to you in a currency you don’t hold.
Block or unblock payments for duplicate invoice IDs.
Block or unblock payments from customers who have non-U.S. PayPal accounts.
Block or unblock payments from Student Account holders.



Log in to your PayPal business account at www.paypal.com. Click the
 profile icon (Profile menu) on the top right side of the page. From the
 Business Profile menu, select Profile and Settings.

Note: If you do not see the profile icon on the top right, select 
Profile which appears in the top menu when the My Account tab is selected.

From the left menu, click My selling tools.

In the Getting paid and managing my risk section, click the Update link
 for the Block Payments item.

Update your settings and click Save.
```

Comment: Followed this and tried again, but it still doesn't work. I know it's from 2015, but I still have this problem with Magento 2.2.1

Comment: @YannBergonzat It's really an annoying issue. I just shared my experience in this thread, not sure it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just happened to hit this problem with Magento 2.3.1, when paying with credit card against PayPal Payflow Pro. Our default currency for the store is "CAD".

The support team is super, after our several failed transactions they managed to figure our the problem, let me share their reply here:

> Thanks for reaching out today. Happy to help.
>
> It looks as though this is an issue with the currency code you're passing. Right now it appears you're trying to pass USD in on the $0.00 verification call, but CAD on the actual 2.20 transaction itself. When you verify a card, the transaction you attempt against that verification must use the same currency. Try passing the subsequent transaction with USD, or create the verification in CAD and then run the transaction against it using CAD. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-account-verifications for more on verifications. That's a great resource for Payflow in general as well.
>
> That should resolve the issue you're seeing, but please let us know if you run into any other issues.
>
> I hope that helps. Let us know if you have any questions.

That says for two API calls from our server (Magento 2.3.1) to PayPal need to specify the same currency code. While our first API call which sending `amt=0` field doesn't have separate currency field there, so I guess the default value was assigned which is "USD". While the second API call which sending the real amt number had `currency=CAD` field, that might confused the API and eventually refused by it.

For Magento 2.3.1 the fix is to add the `currency` filed for the first API call, which the same idea may apply to other conditions as well.

[Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22399) is the Magento fix in case you are interested.